# What are .RDX and .RDB files for R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate some results from a paper, namely **Table 1** from "Cause-Specific Cumulative Incidence Estimation and the Fine andGray Model Under Both Left Truncation and Right Censoring" Geskus (2011).

At the end of the paper is a link to [files](http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/datasets/090931M.htm), some of which I assume are data files. Within these files are two with *.rdx* and *.rdb* extensions. What exactly are these and how do I open them in R?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the link you give leads to just two files. The first is a pdf file, as I'm sure you know. The second is a zip file containing an R package. You are supposed to unzip the file, then copy the folder "crhaz" to the "library" folder of your R installation. Then you run R and type library(crhaz) at the R prompt.

You don't have to worry about any of the individual files that you might see in the package folder. The .rdx and .rdb files are binary files storing builds of R code and are only for internal use within R -- you cannot open them yourself.

This is what I am sure the authors of the article expect you to do. I will say however that they have done a poor job of distributing their R package. They should provide a build of the package than can be installed using install.packages(), but they have instead just zipped the image of the Windows installation of their package.

**Later**

After a little more investigation, I can see that the crhaz package provided by Ronald Geskus with the 2011 article contained only one function, called crprep, and this function has recently been made part of the CRAN package "mstate".  So you can now get the function for use in an up-to-date version of R by installing mstate:

```
    install.packages(mstate)
    library(mstate)
    ?crprep
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me Gordon. I followed your steps but when I call the library in R I get the error: "_Error: package ‘crhaz’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it_". Problem is I don't know how to reinstall it?

Comment: @StatsPlease, the authors built their package using R 2.10.0, so the only way you can use it is to use R 2.10.0 yourself (or any R version 2.X.X). You can't re-install it for later versions of R because the authors didn't provide you with the source code version. This is the whole reason why their method of distributing the package is wrong.

Comment: @StatsPlease, I've edited my answer to show a better solution. The code from 2011 is best ignored now.

Comment: Thanks again. The reason I was doing all of this was because when I use _crprep_, I don't replicate the values from Table 1 in his paper. So I was trying to investigate further (which led me to the .rdx, .rdb files).